# Checkout Control Panel that updates pricing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my first post here.

I am not much of a programmer, I can tailor some things for my personal needs but thats about it.

I am looking for a script (jQuery preferred I suppose) which is easy to incorporate and bind to a few DIVs to be updated dynamically.

Nothing too deep, just something that can updated price at check-out...

Could I get some recommendations on a solid and simple widget for this?

I appreciate any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/ajaxed-sliding-shopping-cart-with-jquery/